# Tiff or JPG in PDF?

Tags: pdf, compression, jpeg, tiff

I have a bunch of scanned PDF (e.g. picturebased pdfs). When I run them through "pdf optimizers" online they frequently are reduced 70-80 % in size with hardly any noticeable difference in quality. I think I heard somewhere that PDF uses either JPG och TIFF for pictures. How can I determine if my PDFs in fact are TIFF-based?

Answer (score 0):

TIFF is usually used in its lossless variant, and its
[compression schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Compression)
are pretty limited.

JPEG, on the other hand, can be reduced quite a lot, by reducing the image
quality. It also has a very good compression scheme.

So, for such dramatic reductions of 70-80 %, the image has to be in JPEG format.